How migrate and use dartsass-sprockets with rails 6?
I use gem 'sass-rails' on rails (6.1.7.6), I want try to use gem 'dartsass-sprockets' (because I have to use sprockets), I bundle install and don't modify other thing at this point.
I get this error :
Error: /home/matrix/.rbenv/versions/3.0.6/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/dartsass-sprockets-3.0.0/lib/sassc/rails/importer.rb:103:in `join': [1mno implicit conversion of Sass::Importers::Filesystem into String ([1;4mTypeError[m[1m)[m

any idea of how migrate correctly ?
gemfile:

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails.git
  revision: f6391d0d30fa63bb9bf6cd94e0e5608012584e6e
  specs:
    compass-rails (4.0.0)
      compass (~> 1.0.0)
      sass-rails (< 5.1)
      sprockets (< 4.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.7.6)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.7.6)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.6)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.6)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.6)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.7.6)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.6)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.6)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.7.6)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.7.6)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.6)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.6)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
    activerecord (6.1.7.6)
      activemodel (= 6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
    activestorage (6.1.7.6)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.6)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.6)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.7.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.8.6)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    base64 (0.2.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.20)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    chunky_png (1.3.15)
    coderay (1.1.3)
    coffee-rails (5.0.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    compass (1.0.3)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      compass-core (~> 1.0.2)
      compass-import-once (~> 1.0.5)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      sass (>= 3.3.13, < 3.5)
    compass-core (1.0.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
    compass-import-once (1.0.5)
      sass (>= 3.2, < 3.5)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.2)
    connection_pool (2.4.1)
    crass (1.0.6)
    date (3.3.4)
    domain_name (0.6.20240107)
    eco (1.0.0)
      coffee-script
      eco-source
      execjs
    eco-source (1.1.0.rc.1)
    em-websocket (0.5.3)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0)
    erubi (1.12.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.7)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faraday (2.9.0)
      faraday-net_http (>= 2.0, < 3.2)
    faraday-multipart (1.0.4)
      multipart-post (~> 2)
    faraday-net_http (3.1.0)
      net-http
    ffi (1.16.3)
    formatador (1.1.0)
    fullcalendar-rails (3.9.0.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 4.0.5, < 5.0.0)
      jquery-ui-rails (>= 5.0.2)
      momentjs-rails (>= 2.9.0)
    globalid (1.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 6.1)
    guard (2.18.1)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.12, < 2.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.13.0)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-livereload (2.5.2)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      guard (~> 2.8)
      guard-compat (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.8)
    hashie (5.0.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.5)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    http_parser.rb (0.8.0)
    i18n (1.14.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    image_size (2.1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.6.0)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (2.7.1)
    jwt (2.7.1)
    kaminari (1.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.2.2)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.2.2)
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-actionview (1.2.2)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.2.2)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-core (1.2.2)
    koala (3.5.0)
      addressable
      faraday
      faraday-multipart
      json (>= 1.8)
      rexml
    libv8 (3.16.14.19.1-x86_64-linux)
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    loofah (2.22.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.12.0)
    lumberjack (1.2.10)
    mail (2.8.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    marcel (1.0.2)
    mechanize (2.9.1)
      addressable (~> 2.8)
      domain_name (~> 0.5, >= 0.5.20190701)
      http-cookie (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
      mime-types (~> 3.0)
      net-http-digest_auth (~> 1.4, >= 1.4.1)
      net-http-persistent (>= 2.5.2, < 5.0.dev)
      nokogiri (~> 1.11, >= 1.11.2)
      rubyntlm (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.3)
      webrick (~> 1.7)
      webrobots (~> 0.1.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mime-types (3.5.2)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2023.1205)
    mini_mime (1.1.5)
    minitest (5.21.1)
    momentjs-rails (2.29.4.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.3.0)
    mysql2 (0.5.5)
    nenv (0.3.0)
    net-http (0.4.1)
      uri
    net-http-digest_auth (1.4.1)
    net-http-persistent (4.0.2)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2)
    net-imap (0.4.9.1)
      date
      net-protocol
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.2.2)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.4.0.1)
      net-protocol
    nio4r (2.7.0)
    nokogiri (1.16.0-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    notiffany (0.1.3)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    oauth2 (2.0.9)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 3.0)
      jwt (>= 1.0, < 3.0)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 4)
      snaky_hash (~> 2.0)
      version_gem (~> 1.1)
    oily_png (1.2.1)
      chunky_png (~> 1.3.7)
    omniauth (2.1.2)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6)
      rack (>= 2.2.3)
      rack-protection
    omniauth-facebook (9.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.8.0)
      oauth2 (>= 1.4, < 3)
      omniauth (~> 2.0)
    pry (0.14.2)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    public_suffix (5.0.4)
    puma (6.4.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.7.3)
    rack (2.2.8)
    rack-livereload (0.5.2)
      rack (< 3)
    rack-protection (3.2.0)
      base64 (>= 0.1.0)
      rack (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.4)
    rack-test (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (6.1.7.6)
      actioncable (= 6.1.7.6)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.7.6)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.7.6)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.6)
      actiontext (= 6.1.7.6)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.6)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.6)
      activemodel (= 6.1.7.6)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.6)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.7.6)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
      minitest
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.6.0)
      loofah (~> 2.21)
      nokogiri (~> 1.14)
    rails-timeago (2.20.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
    railties (6.1.7.6)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.6)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.6)
      method_source
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rake (13.1.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    redis (5.0.8)
      redis-client (>= 0.17.0)
    redis-client (0.19.1)
      connection_pool
    redis-namespace (1.11.0)
      redis (>= 4)
    ref (2.0.0)
    rexml (3.2.6)
    rubyntlm (0.6.3)
    sanitize (6.1.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.12.0)
    sass (3.4.25)
    sass-rails (5.0.8)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    snaky_hash (2.0.1)
      hashie
      version_gem (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
    spring (2.1.1)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    therubyracer (0.12.3)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.15)
      ref
    thor (1.3.0)
    tilt (2.3.0)
    timeout (0.4.1)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    uri (0.13.0)
    version_gem (1.1.3)
    web-console (4.2.1)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webrick (1.8.1)
    webrobots (0.1.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.6)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    zeitwerk (2.6.12)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt
  byebug
  coffee-rails
  compass-rails!
  eco
  execjs (~> 2.7.0)
  fullcalendar-rails
  guard (>= 2.1.0)
  guard-livereload
  image_size (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  kaminari
  koala
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  mechanize
  momentjs-rails
  mysql2
  oily_png
  omniauth-facebook
  puma
  rack-livereload
  rails (~> 6)
  rails-timeago (~> 2.0)
  rb-fsevent
  redis
  redis-namespace
  sanitize
  sass-rails
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  therubyracer
  turbolinks
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.33



The gems supports Rails 6.1. Which exact version are you on?

Also Rails 6.0 only supports Ruby >= 2.5.0 < 3.0.0

I use ruby 3+ and rails 6.1+ (6.1.7.6 exactly)

Can you post your Gemfile? When searching that error most of the issues seem to relate to conflicts between certain gems.

I update with gemfile, I see compass-rails use sass-rails, maybe this is a part of problem? but now, how use compass with dart sass?^^

you need to drop compass, it hasn't been maintained in over a decade. otherwise, you're stuck with sass-rails.

do you have some actual tools to do sprite like compass?
